# Effective use of sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets, signals

I have an application where I have to send Signals and Data between two entities.
Which way is best practice and why?

1. Open 4 sockets, 2 for signals in both directions and 2 for data in both directions
2. Open 2 sockets each for data and signals
3. Just open 1 socket and filter for signals and data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all sockets are full-duplex, i.e. you don't need a separate socket (connection) for sending and receiving.

Secondly, it's hard to tell without going into more details. However knowing the history of HTTP (one connection for commands/headers and data) and FTP (separate connections for commands and data) seems like HTTP designers made a better choice. Two connections is more code to maintain, also some firewalls don't like hanging, idle FTP command connection when large portions of data are transferred.

So, go for one connection, it's easy to distinguish between signals and data (flag, header, etc.) Also incoming and outgoing channel is completely orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the HTTP/FTP reasoning makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just have 1 socket for all data and 1 socket for all signals. You can send signals to the remote entity while reading signals from the remote entity from the same socket. This is sort of like how FTP (non-passive) works, you have a control connection and then one used for the actual data transfer.

Having 4 sockets seems overkill, but I don't know the context of what the signals or data are.

If you don't mind more code to decode the network communication, you can definitely do it all in one socket. It'll require more thought into the actual communication, a better "protocol" if you will. Both the 2 socket and 1 socket model are fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible "middle way" - use JBoss remoting or similar to multiplex several virtual sockets on top of one real one. That way you can keep the data and control channels separate at the application level but still require only one TCP port (and thus at most one firewall hole) at the operating system level.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: use a dedicated middleware, built for [realtime application like 0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ajava).

To instantiate ØMQ:

```
Jzmq obj = new Jzmq (hostname);
```

Where hostname is name or IP address of the box where zmq_server is running.

To create wiring, createExchange, createQueue and bind functions can be used. For detailed description of how wiring mechanism works have a look here.

```
int eid = obj.createExchange ("E", Jzmq.SCOPE_GLOBAL, "10.0.0.1:5555");
obj.createQueue ("Q", Jzmq.SCOPE_GLOBAL, "10.0.0.1:5556");
obj.bind ("E", "Q");
```

Sending a message is pretty straightforward. Message is supplied in form of byte array:

```
byte msg [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
obj.send (eid, msg);
```

Receiving a message is even more simple:

```
byte [] msg = obj.receive ();
```

Full sample [available here](http://www.zeromq.org/deleted%3awhitepapers%3ajava).